# Google Merchant Orders - 414 Error, URL too long to process

Tags: http-status-codes, http-error, merchant-account

Any time there is more than 25 orders in my merchant orders list, and I have to page through to see the next 50, 75, etc, I get a 414 error 'url is too long. that's all we know.' message from Google.

I looked at the URL, which is generated by Google by the way, and it's over 2300 characters long... I know that 2000 is the approximate limit on URLs in terms of characters for most browsers. I contacted Google's support staff and though they were very nice,  they were more clueless than I was.

Has anyone else ever encountered this issue?

Thank you!

see image here: http://postimg.org/image/m67ob8lmf/

Comment: I can confirm this issue on my Wallet merchant portal as well.   It's only gotten worse in the past few days.  I use to be able to navigate to the 3rd page.  Now I can't even navigate to the second page.   I talked to a first line tech support person who had me go through the standard "clear browser cache" exercise, which did nothing.  They also asked me to submit a screenshot, although I had already submitted 5 pevious screenshots (no exaggeration).  Rant:   pretty unbelievable this is an acceptable bug for a merchant processing portal, and would persist for days on end. ... *sigh*... Google.

Comment: sghael, things started working again for me about 2 days ago, after a long back and forth with google's support team (which I'm not sure really did much). In any case, things are working again here for us, hope the same is true for you.